# Vuex: Lifecycle hooks

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following data structure in vuex file:

```
state:{
    info:[
      {
        name: 'Some field 1',
        value: '',
        pattern: /.+/,
        //status: ''
      },
      {
        name: 'Some field 2',
        value: '',
        pattern: /.+/,
       // status: ''
      }
    ]
```

I would like every object to have a field `status: ''`.But I do not want to duplicate the code. In Vue component I wrote for this:

```
beforeMount(){ 
            // add new fuild 
        }
```

But this way does not work in Vuex.

```
beforeMount(){  
    console.log('does not work');
    for (let i = 0; i < this.info.length; i++) {
        this.$set(this.state.info[i], 'status', '');
    }
  }
```

How to add a new field into state dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

In a mutation just do something like this:

```
  state.info = state.info.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  status: ''
})
```